# how to create and polulate a geometry columns in sqlite3

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite, gis

I am creating a test database on my local machine so I can test some calculations before moving to a bigger run to be saved against the actual postgres database. But I can't get `sqlite3` to create and save data to my `geom` columns (which is being correctly created by python). It seems like the `geom` column doesn't get created either. Any help will be appreciated.

```
conn = lite.connect('geom_test.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE test
(
lat double precision,
long double precision,
speed double precision)"""))
c.execute(""" 
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('test', 'geom',
4326, 'POINT', 'XY');""")

line = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
line.AddPoint_2D(lon,lat)
line = line.ExportToWkt()

qry ="INSERT INTO sequence VALUES (?,?,?,?);"
conn = lite.connect('geom_test.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.executemany(qry, data) #data is 4 columns dict 
c.close()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Can you add what errors you're getting (or, if no errors, confirm that it's failing silently)?

Comment: `AddGeometryColumn` doesn't look like something that sqlite should be able to understand... is that something from your gis library? then it will only be known to python, but not to sqlite.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using SpatiaLite, which adds functionality to SQLite. See [Recipe #6: Creating a new Geometry column](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-cookbook/html/new-geom.html). The next slide shows how to load some simple geometries into the table.

See the [main web resource for SpatiaLite](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/index), with cookbooks, references, etc. And if you need to view the geometries, try QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the spatialite shared library :

```
import sqlite3 as lite
from os.path import realpath
conn = lite.connect('geom_test.db')
library_path = "/usr/local/lib/mod_spatialite.so"  # on my ubuntu linux
conn.enable_load_extension(True)
conn.load_extension(realpath(library_path))
```

Or another way to load the extension :

```
conn.execute("SELECT load_extension(?, 'sqlite3_modspatialite_init');",
             (realpath(library_path),))
```

On windows the name will be 'mod_spatialite.dll' (Also be careful to the path provided to the load_extension(), ie. properly escaping problematic characters and resolving symbolic links before calling it).
Anyway [this page on SpatiaLite website](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=mod_spatialite) show some details about the loading of the shared library.

Edit:
The loading will raise an `OperationalError` if it fails. If it success, you can check if it use the versions you expected (and do the operations you were trying to do, of course):

```
vs = str([i for i in c.execute("""SELECT spatialite_version()""")])
vgeos = str([i for i in c.execute("""SELECT geos_version()""")]
print('Spatialite {} (GEOS {})'.format(
              vs.strip("()[]',"), vgeos.strip("()',[]")))
```

Comment: i have tried to load that extension but i have been unsuccessful  so far.

Comment: @user1234 did you try to get the real path of the shared library before loading it ? On my linux computer it fails if I don't get the real path at first with something like : `In [2]: os.path.realpath('/usr/local/lib/mod_spatialite.so')
Out[2]: '/usr/local/lib/mod_spatialite.so.7.1.0' ` I will edit my answer

Comment: Sorry..! it will also probably be unsuccessful...but as you are on python 2.7 i thought also you maybe can try to install the [pyspatialite package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyspatialite/3.0.1-alpha-0) but i guess its a bit deprecated. If you can install it, it will work as the sqlite3 module but already spatially enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using PostGIS, which adds functionality to PostgreSQL.  Included in this is the `AddGeometryColumn` function.  This won't be available to SQLite, as it isn't a standard function.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you're trying to create a table with a geometry column in SQLite, which isn't supported directly. Unlike PostgreSQL with PostGIS extension, SQLite doesn't have native support for geometry types.

However, if you're using Python and need spatial capabilities, you might consider using a library like GeoAlchemy or GeoPandas along with SQLAlchemy. These libraries allow you to work with spatial data in Python and can handle database operations with spatial columns.

Here's how you might modify your code to work with GeoAlchemy:

python_code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Float
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry

Base = declarative_base()

class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    lat = Column(Float)
    long = Column(Float)
    speed = Column(Float)
    geom = Column(Geometry('POINT'))

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///geom_test.db')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```